# How do you convert a lvalue to an rvalue? And what happens to the `new` lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I would like to move an object into a `std::vector` using `std::vector::push_back()`.  This would seem to be possible since there is a [`std::vector::push_back(value_type&& val)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) function.  But due to the the existence of `std::vector::push_back(value_type const & val)`, which copies and would be the overriding call, I need to convert the lvalue object to an rvalue.

How is this done?

Example:

```
struct X { int x; X(int x) : x(x) {} };

int main()
{
    std::vector<X> ax;
    X x(3);
    ax.push_back(x);  // <= Want to move x in to vector ax, not copy.
    return 0;
}
```

Actually, maybe it can't be?  I ask this because after writing this example, my new questions are:

- If I do move `x` into `ax`, what is the value of `x.x`?  If `X` had an explicit destructor, what would happen to `x` when it leaves scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`std::move()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move):

```
ax.push_back(std::move(x));
```

Concerning your question:

> If I do move x into ax, what is the value of x.x?

In this case, your class `X` does not contain an explicitly declared move constructor, so the compiler will generate one that does memberwise move of `X`'s members. Since `X` only has one member of type `int`, and moving an `int` is no different from copying it, then `x.x` will have the same value it had before being moved from.

> If X had an explicit destructor, what would happen to x when it leaves scope?

If `X` has a user-declared destructor, that will inhibit the generation of an implicit move constructor - but not that of an implicit copy constructor. Therefore, this function call:

```
ax.push_back(std::move(x));
```

Will result in `x` being *copied* into `ax`. In any case, `x` will be destroyed when going out of scope, since it has automatic storage duration - no matter whether a user-declared destructor is present or not.

In general, one should not make assumptions on the state of an object that has been moved from, except that that state is valid (paragraph 17.6.5.15/1 of the C++11 Standard guarantees this to be the case for types of the Standard Library).

In concrete, this means that *the only functions that can safely work with an object that has been moved from are those that do not have any precondition on the state of that object*. Typically, two such functions are the destructor and the (copy- or move-) assignment operator.

Comment: Oh, as simple as that eh?  What about my other two questions at the end?

Comment: And if it had an explicit one?  Although I wrote a simplistic example, I'd like a full understanding and is why I stipulated `if X had an explicit destructor...`

Comment: So, if we replace `X` with `std::string` (and of course `x(3)` with `x("3")`), I won't actually be moving the string object.  It will only be copied?

Comment: @Adrian: It will be moved, because `std::string` has a user-declared move constructor

Comment: So if you were to include a move constructor in a class, you would have to ensure that the object you are moving from retains a valid state such that the destructor will handle the object that was moved from.

Comment: @Adrian: Yes, that's correct. For instance, for types of the Standard Library, you can't tell what state a moved-from object is left in, but you can tell for sure it is a valid state. So all functions that have no pre-conditions on the state of that object can be invoked. One such function is necessarily the destructor. Another one is usually the (copy- or move-) assignment operator.

Comment: I assume that you meant `So all functions that have <s>no</s> pre-conditions on the state of the object can be invoked`, since if it has no pre-conditions, it means that it can be invoked no matter what the object's state.  Also, I believe that your last statement (with correction) should be added to your answer as it describes what must occur with the 'new' lvalue due to the invocation of move semantics if a user defined move constructor is specified, which IHMO, would be a more complete answer.

Comment: @Adrian: Well, that's what I wrote, isn't it? Perhaps you missed the "no" in that sentence? ;)

Comment: The comments don't appear to accept the strikeout tag.  By stating *no*, you are stating that they can be invoked.  But they could have been invoked anyway.  It is the ones that have a pre-condition that are the ones that are important.  I.e. the destructor has a pre-condition.

Comment: @Adrian: I think you're misunderstanding. Functions that have no pre-conditions can be invoked, and functions that have pre-conditions cannot (because you don't know what state the object is in). Destructors have *no* pre-conditions, which is why they can be invoked.

Comment: The object must be in a valid state is the pre-condition, its implied.  Only a function that doesn't rely on anything has none.

Comment: @Adrian: But that is just the class invariant. All functions have implicitly that pre-condition - but the destructor has no *additional* pre-condition (like the object must be in such a state or such a state).

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of the case where the class invariant can be made temporarily invalid between member function calls.  However, since the destructor is not called directly by the member function, I agree.  In any case, I think that your statement which I referred to should be added to the answer for completeness, instead of someone having to troll through the comments to find it.

Comment: I take it that you don't agree?

Comment: @Adrian: I just did not feel like :) And I rejected your first edit because it was not completely correct. But I will add it